# MIPS: String Copy, Pass-by-reference

Tags: pass-by-reference, mips

I am looking to implement string copy and I am not doing it correctly. I am given a string 'x' and I want to 
1] copy the entire string 'x' into 'y'
2] copy the first 5 characters of 'x' into 'y'

and I want to pass arguments by reference.

```
.data
    x:  .asciiz "Hi, How do you do?"
    y:  .word   0:5


.text
.globl main

_copy:
    lw  $t0,    ($a0)
    la  $a0,    y
    sw  $t0,    ($a0)
    li  $v0,    4   
    syscall
    jr  $ra 

main:
    la  $a0,    x
    jal _copy
    jr  $ra
    nop
```

Comment: What is the question? You're currently passing the address of the string, which would qualify as pass by reference.

Comment: Hi Michael, my question, just as it is in the original post is regarding copying strings. I have solved the first part of it. How do I copy *a part* of a string into another?

Comment: I assume that your solution to the first problem was a loop that runs until a NULL character is found. The solution for the second problem would be the same, except that you exit the loop after `num` iterations (where `num` is the number of characters to copy) _or_  a NULL character is found.